# How can i make the icon change when it is clicked

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I want the arrow to change and display the visibility widget when about me is clicked on the image.

[image]

Comment: can you include your code-snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your attached image, you can simply get the effect using  [ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html).

How-ever to change icon based on click

- create a `bool _isExpanded = false` inside `state` class.
- On expand changes, use `setstate` to  change the value.
  Using assigning the icon

```dart
Icon(_isExpanded?
          Icons.arrow_downward
          :Icons.arrow_upward,
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int angle = 0; 
 RotatedBox(
          quarterTurns: angle,
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                angle = 1;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
```